# Is it safe to use time.Now().Unix(), UnixNano(), UnixMilli() etc? What about integer overflow?

Tags: go, unix-timestamp

I read here https://pkg.go.dev/time#Unix that Unix() returns `the local Time corresponding to the given Unix time, sec seconds and nsec nanoseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC`

And you can also get the milliseconds since, or nanoseconds since 1970 using UnixNano() and UnixMilli() respectively.

I guess I'm confused as to how this is safe. Won't there be a date/time cut off where the number of nano, milli or regular seconds exceeds int64's capacity?

Also, I was experimenting on go playground https://go.dev/play/ by printing out `time.Now.Unix()`, I would always get 1257894000 seconds, even if I ran my code like a minute apart.

However I did see a difference if I did

```
time.Now.Unix()
time.Sleep(time.Duration(1) * time.Second)
time.Now.Unix()
```

Which gave me 1257894000 and 1257894001.

I'm confused how Unix time works basically.

Comment: (((9223372036854775807/(10^9))/60)/24)/365 = 17548.27 years. We will not survive long enough to see it.

Comment: Of course there's a cutoff. Unless you have infinite capacity, there's always a cutoff. the question is whether it's a relevant cutoff.

Comment: The playground page where you ran the program explains why you see the same time over server runs of the program: *In the playground the time begins at 2009-11-10 23:00:00 UTC (determining the significance of this date is an exercise for the reader). This makes it easier to cache programs by giving them deterministic output.*

Answer (score 5):

`Time.Unix()`, `Time.UnixMicro()`, `Time.UnixMilli()`, `Time.UnixNano()` all return signed int64s.

The max signed int64 is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

This means `Time.Unix()` won't run out of integers for *292 billion years*. It will undoubtedly outlive humanity.

The worst case scenario is `Time.UnixNano()` which will run out of integers on `Friday, April 11, 2262 11:47:16.854 PM GMT`. I don't know about you, but I'll be dead and hopefully no one will be using my code.

Comment: I'd be happy if I found out someone used my code 160 years after I died